# How to find the name of the wireless network device by IP Address Android?

Tags: android

I have a list of Ip addresses on my local network and I want to know which device holds each address, how can I know?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the docs of `InetAddress`:

> **Host Name Resolution** 
>   Host name-to-IP address resolution is
>   accomplished through the use of a combination of local machine
>   configuration information and network naming services such as the
>   Domain Name System (DNS) and Network Information Service(NIS). The
>   particular naming services(s) being used is by default the local
>   machine configured one. For any host name, its corresponding IP
>   address is returned.
>
> **Reverse name resolution means that for any IP address, the host
>   associated with the IP address is returned.**
>
> The InetAddress class provides methods to resolve host names to their
>   IP addresses and vice versa.

This method would then be [`InetAddress.getHostName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

Create an InetAddress object with the ip address then call getHostName on it

```
InetAddress inetAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.20");
String hostname = inetAddr.getHostName();
```

Be aware though that there is no guarantee that reverse lookup is done when instantiating the inetAddress object like this on Android, so you will need to check that the value of hostname is not null before using it.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work in Android it just returns me only the IP address, not the name